# Unable to scan GCR image through Jenkins

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I am trying to build a sample docker image, push it to GCR and scan it on GCR using a jenkins stage. I am able to create it, push it but scan isnt working. Not sure what needs to be the stage steps for scanning. Below is small snip of what i did.

```
    stage('Push Image') {
        steps {
            script{
                    docker.withRegistry('https://us.gcr.io/', '*My Jenkins - GCP Connection Credentials here*') {
                image.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
                image.push("latest")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('GCR Scan image') {
        steps {
            script{
              gcrImageVulnerabilityScanner imageName: '<NEED HELP ON WHAT NEEDS TO GO HERE>'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share what error did you encounter?

Comment: It seems like you need to pass the Imagename to the gcrImageVulnerabilityScanner plugin. So us.gcr.io/repo_name/image_name:tag

Comment: @SarahRemo I got an error similar to https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63700. Looks like there is no solution yet. Please help if you know about this Grafeas client.

Comment: @boredabdel I used similar and then got error related to https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63700
ERROR: null
Something went wrong while setting up GrafeasClient...

Comment: Can you try this documentation regarding GCR Vulnerability Scanner https://plugins.jenkins.io/gcr-scanner/?

Answer (score 0):

There is the resuorce URL of your image, for example

```
gcr.io/project-id/image@sha256:SHA_ID
```